# How to set the css style display property in json success function

Tags: jquery, css, json

I am getting some values to my html elements from the json.
Initially my image block will be hidden and i want to make it to display/show only when the name is entered.
I tried $("#imgblock").show(); but it is not working.
My code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function loadmemberg(m)
{
   $.ajax({
   type   : "POST",
   url    : "details.php",
   data   : {gvalue:m},
   success: function(data){
   var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
     $('#name').val(obj[0].FullName);
     $('#place').val(obj[0].PlaceName);
     $("#image").attr("src", obj[0].ImageFileName);
  var obj="";
     },
  error: function(data){
  alert("Please Enter a valid details");  
  }
  }); 
 }
</script>
<html>
<div><input type="text" id="name"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="place"/></div>
<div style="display:none" id="imgblock"><img src="" id="image"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: the issue is with the `display:none` style on the parentElement of `img#image`. that is what you need to change..

Comment: That was written wrong,  I have corrected my code. Please check again. Yes i have styled it on the parent element, still not working

Comment: are the inputs `name` and `place` getting the values assigned? if no: how are you firing off `loadmemberg`... 

.. are you getting the error alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I placed $("#imgblock").show(); just after  success: function(data){
 It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

the error seems to be with the ImageFileName, for your functionality is correct. Though, in my implementation.. I'm using `$("#image").parent().css("display","block");`

---

### Code Sample

In this code sample, I'm using mock data, and I have to handle the functionality in the ajax error handler, because Allow-Cross-Origin will be null.

```js
//var url = "details.php";

url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

function loadmemberg(m)
{
   $.ajax({
   type   : "POST",
   url    : url,
   data   : {gvalue:m},
   success: function(data){
     
   //var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
     var obj = [{"FullName": "Jason Borne", "PlaceName":"Paris, France", "ImageFileName" : "http://www.nysun.com/pics/939.jpg"}]
     $('#name').val(obj[0].FullName);
     $('#place').val(obj[0].PlaceName);
     $("#image").attr("src", obj[0].ImageFileName);
     
     var imgWrapper = $("#image").parent();
     imgWrapper.css("display","block");
     },
     error: function(data){
       // alert("Please Enter a valid details");  suppressing error for this test
       var obj = [{"FullName": "Jason Borne", "PlaceName":"Paris, France", "ImageFileName" : "http://www.nysun.com/pics/939.jpg"}]
     $('#name').val(obj[0].FullName);
     $('#place').val(obj[0].PlaceName);
     $("#image").attr("src", obj[0].ImageFileName);
     var imgWrapper = $("#image").parent();
     imgWrapper.css("display","block");
     }
   }); 
}


loadmemberg(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" id="name"/></div>
<div><input type="text" id="place"/></div>
<div style="display:none"><img src="" id="image"></div>
```